# Display address on map on my page

Tags: javascript, html, maps

If I have an address string (New Jersey, Hoboken), what is the simplest way to display the address(simple address) on map in my page?(no preference for the source of the map).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are less familiar with how to setup a Google Maps embed on your website this site will help you generate the appropriate code:

http://www.trivoo.net/google-maps/

If you are more familiar with HTML/JS you could go the more involved route of using Google Maps JavaScript API found here.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/

They have great documentation there on how to set it up.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would be to use [Google My Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/d/), you can enter an address and Google will generate some code you can embed on your page.